# perl env path in .bashrc

Tags: perl, path

I am running Manjaro Linux and perl 5.20.1, which came pre-installed.

I have started learning perl and need to get it in my path in `~/.bashrc`. (Manjaro uses `.bashrc` and not `.bash_profile`). I should be able to run my scripts from `./script.pl` anywhere in my `~/`. I have to now go to the directory where they are, make executable then type `perl myscript.pl`.

Can't I add a `$PATH` and be able to just run from `./myscript.pl`?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer you are looking for is point 3, but just in case I have added points 1 and 2:

1. If you run

   ```
   perl script.pl
   ```

   then you do not need to make the file executable. If a file is not executable then you pass the name of the script, as an argument, to the perl command.
2. If you can run `perl` without specifying a path (i.e. `/usr/bin/perl script.pl`), then the perl executable is *already* in your path env (because you are not specifying a path).
3. If you want to run the script without specifying the command `perl` explicitly, then you don't need to add anything to your PATH env, you instead specify the path **in the script**. So, in addition to making the script executable (which you have already done), put this as the **first** line of the script

   ```
   #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
   ```

   Change the path in the script accordingly to specify the correct path. `which perl` will tell you the path to your perl executable.

So, for example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
print "Hello World!\n";
```

Now, you can run it with `./script.pl`